# return the position of all circles from an image

Tags: python, opencv

Disclaimer: I'm not really a good python programmer, I'm an android developer, so if you see anything dumb, don't be suprised

The example images I'm working with:

before modifying:
[image]

after:
[image]

I'm trying to get the positions of all circles in the second image (only 5 of them) to later use pyautogui to move the cursor to the positions and press them, however the cv2.HoughCircles returns   a lot of positions and I'm not sure why is that, is there any way to get only the desired (X,Y) positions as a list?

current result:
(not even sure whether those are positions tbh)

```
[[[ 577.   603.   196.2]
  [ 579.   593.   188. ]
  [ 475.   319.    37.6]
  [ 613.   391.   123.4]
  [ 575.   613.   205.6]
  [ 415.   469.   164.2]
  [ 617.   371.   135.6]
  [ 575.   259.    38.6]
  [ 583.   581.   176.2]
  [ 587.   385.   118.8]
  [ 475.   443.    37.2]
  [ 285.   381.   315.2]
  [ 589.   357.   114. ]
  [ 579.   503.    37.6]
  [ 571.   391.   125.2]
  [ 621.   383.   125.2]
  [ 539.   379.   123.6]
  [ 585.   347.   123.2]
  [ 575.   357.   113.4]
  [ 409.   459.   169.2]
  [ 571.   347.   121.4]
  [ 571.   407.   113. ]
  [ 591.   611.   201. ]
  [ 541.   393.   120.4]
  [ 683.   375.   186. ]
  [ 685.   443.    36.2]
  [ 255.   391.   326.4]
  [ 563.   355.   112. ]
  [ 587.   401.   104.6]
  [ 577.   627.   201. ]
  [ 617.   311.   183.2]
  [ 523.   669.   264.6]
  [ 615.   611.   216. ]
  [ 575.   379.   109. ]
  [ 335.   753.   446.2]
  [ 531.   395.   110. ]
  [ 477.   511.   101.4]
  [ 603.   613.   215. ]
  [ 135.   431.   440.2]
  [ 197.   439.   380.6]
  [ 555.   411.   112.8]
  [ 301.   435.   277.2]
  [ 579.   637.   185.6]
  [ 425.   487.   157.6]
  [ 577.   369.    99.2]
  [ 151.   435.   424. ]
  [ 207.   319.   411. ]
  [ 587.   373.   106.4]
  [ 493.   519.    90.2]
  [ 227.   435.   352.4]
  [ 291.   435.   284.2]
  [ 385.   505.   186.6]
  [ 943.   613.   536.8]
  [ 515.   677.   270. ]
  [ 241.   439.   340.8]
  [ 971.   613.   563.2]
  [ 931.   613.   524.4]
  [ 223.   323.   396.8]
  [ 487.   509.   101.8]
  [ 291.   315.   256.2]
  [ 175.   439.   400.4]
  [ 579.   659.   205. ]
  [ 495.   529.    88.6]
  [ 291.   447.   286.6]
  [ 403.   509.   165.6]
  [ 475.   529.    93.8]
  [   3.   319.   586. ]
  [  21.   323.   568. ]
  [ 743.   319.   282. ]
  [ 589.   641.   193.2]
  [   7.   443.   572. ]
  [ 161.   319.   436. ]
  [ 165.   439.   410.6]
  [ 497.   507.   100.8]
  [  31.   323.   557.8]
  [1021.   443.   445.2]
  [  51.   435.   530. ]
  [ 681.    33.   445.8]
  [  27.   449.   553.8]
  [  39.   435.   538.8]
  [ 233.   447.   344.4]
  [  49.   323.   540. ]
  [  79.   317.   514.2]
  [ 997.   443.   421.6]
  [ 211.   443.   365.2]
  [ 691.   221.   204.2]
  [ 575.   649.   194.8]
  [ 275.   447.   274. ]
  [ 515.   525.   101.4]
  [  59.   319.   531.6]
  [ 985.   147.   458.8]
  [ 803.   319.   327.2]
  [ 475.   243.   111.2]
  [ 673.   515.   109.4]
  [ 515.   515.    97.8]
  [ 877.   319.   385.6]
  [ 391.   421.   119.6]
  [  69.   435.   512.6]
  [ 107.   435.   468.8]
  [1009.   447.   434.2]
  [ 987.   443.   411.8]
  [ 579.   689.   232.4]
  [ 637.   383.   140.6]
  [ 641.   613.   138.4]
  [ 627.   329.   115.8]
  [ 661.   505.   100.2]
  [ 503.   515.    91. ]
  [ 571.   667.   208.4]
  [ 375.   435.   132.2]
  [ 681.   575.   140. ]
  [ 483.   519.    87.8]
  [ 255.   443.   323.8]
  [ 187.   319.   320.8]
  [ 283.   259.   302.4]
  [ 677.   227.   189.6]
  [ 647.   549.   115.4]
  [ 523.   371.   105.8]
  [ 497.   241.    92.6]
  [ 475.   539.    89. ]
  [ 595.   681.   216.6]
  [ 359.   443.   132.6]
  [ 329.   443.   125.2]
  [ 971.   443.   396. ]
  [ 275.   435.   304.6]
  [ 295.   505.   263. ]
  [ 691.   211.   209.4]
  [ 487.   253.   102.2]
  [ 685.   157.   252.4]
  [ 601.   697.   248.8]
  [ 633.   677.   248. ]
  [ 681.   215.   200.8]
  [ 385.   439.   126.6]
  [ 657.   271.   186. ]
  [ 669.   611.   133.4]
  [ 681.   533.    98. ]
  [ 467.   379.    68.4]
  [ 987.   323.   507. ]
  [ 181.   447.   327.6]
  [ 275.   253.   281.2]
  [ 653.   477.    77.8]
  [ 949.   319.   472.8]
  [ 579.   713.   254.4]
  [ 771.   323.   231. ]
  [ 939.   319.   460. ]
  [ 949.   443.   374.2]
  [ 585.   673.   220.2]
  [ 685.   307.   121.4]
  [ 621.   549.   132.8]
  [ 615.   323.   106.2]
  [ 335.   619.    96.8]
  [ 487.   535.    82.8]
  [ 533.   475.    61.2]
  [ 265.   447.   281.6]
  [ 755.   319.   221.8]
  [ 589.   663.   213.2]
  [ 691.   245.   209.2]
  [ 683.   235.   199.8]
  [ 357.   431.   124.4]
  [ 431.   361.    91.4]
  [ 515.   489.    73.6]
  [  45.   443.   431.6]
  [ 197.   449.   314.4]
  [ 681.   267.   212.2]
  [ 653.   253.   156.2]
  [ 705.   549.   141.4]
  [ 475.   233.    97.8]
  [ 509.   233.    83. ]
  [ 691.   255.   192.8]
  [ 341.   431.   139.6]
  [ 345.   443.   129. ]
  [ 523.   481.    62.8]
  [ 211.   453.   296.4]
  [ 571.   703.   291.6]
  [ 669.   253.   182.8]
  [ 635.   319.   121.6]
  [ 505.   529.    89.8]
  [ 661.   515.    83.6]
  [ 483.   549.    70.8]
  [ 531.   293.    57.6]
  [ 153.   447.   354.4]
  [ 681.   585.   132.4]
  [ 397.   431.   114.4]
  [ 633.   557.   111.8]
  [ 677.   319.   108. ]
  [ 661.   261.   171.6]
  [ 409.   421.   130.4]
  [ 475.   253.   101.6]
  [ 487.   237.   100.6]
  [ 523.   469.    58.6]
  [  15.   453.   463.4]
  [  53.   449.   425.6]
  [ 275.   319.   268.8]
  [ 579.   731.   265. ]
  [ 453.   559.   128.2]
  [ 635.   439.    57.6]
  [  67.   447.   412.6]
  [ 221.   141.   385.8]
  [ 589.   721.   252. ]
  [ 571.   677.   212.2]
  [ 673.   239.   180.8]
  [ 691.   555.   147.2]
  [ 677.   617.   139.8]
  [ 483.   593.   113.6]
  [ 487.   227.    90.6]
  [ 521.   459.    59.4]
  [ 601.   449.    47. ]
  [ 137.   443.   356. ]
  [ 409.    99.   232. ]
  [ 321.   263.   222.4]
  [ 467.   147.   160. ]
  [ 465.   523.    90.6]
  [ 515.   215.    78.2]
  [ 523.   447.    57.6]
  [ 613.   443.    36. ]
  [ 233.   323.   275.2]
  [ 577.   761.   265.8]
  [ 785.   323.   241.8]
  [ 335.   259.   225.4]
  [ 677.   633.   154. ]
  [ 635.   453.    58.4]
  [1005.   549.   506. ]
  [  81.   449.   394.2]
  [ 221.   447.   290.4]
  [ 571.   779.   283.6]
  [ 311.   255.   232.6]
  [ 681.   203.   211.4]
  [ 681.   255.   186.4]
  [ 699.   617.   164. ]
  [ 451.   515.   113.4]
  [ 465.   537.    90. ]
  [ 425.   353.    89.6]
  [ 639.   483.    69.8]
  [ 683.   347.   132. ]
  [ 695.   319.   116. ]
  [ 397.   443.   110. ]
  [ 455.   379.    70.6]
  [ 515.   535.    66. ]
  [  39.   451.   439.2]
  [ 101.   449.   381.6]
  [ 291.   253.   251.4]
  [ 595.   709.   239.6]
  [ 467.   137.   167.6]
  [ 719.   361.   167.2]
  [ 625.   619.   156. ]
  [ 437.   557.   115.2]
  [ 667.   549.    95.8]
  [ 517.   499.    78. ]
  [ 487.   365.    62.2]
  [ 621.   465.    53.2]
  [ 889.   509.   383.8]
  [ 857.   503.   353.6]
  [ 575.   745.   280.2]
  [ 653.   335.   108.8]
  [ 505.   247.    87.8]
  [ 995.   549.   496.8]
  [ 923.   439.   348. ]
  [ 165.   449.   331. ]
  [ 483.   763.   281. ]
  [ 685.   719.   275.4]
  [ 681.   181.   229.8]
  [ 755.   329.   218.2]
  [ 689.   613.   159. ]
  [ 409.   411.   107.4]
  [ 653.   535.   100.8]
  [ 465.   509.    77.8]
  [  83.   439.   406.4]
  [  91.   445.   391. ]
  [ 101.   319.   387. ]
  [ 681.   777.   299.2]
  [ 571.   721.   259.8]
  [ 301.   257.   242.4]
  [ 471.   563.    83.8]
  [ 563.   311.    55. ]
  [ 115.   549.   409. ]
  [ 849.   319.   241. ]
  [ 839.   323.   232.8]
  [ 685.   671.   193.2]
  [ 687.   277.   146.6]
  [ 371.   447.   122.8]
  [ 681.   601.   120.6]
  [ 493.   549.    70.8]
  [ 625.   431.    50.8]
  [ 535.   435.    47. ]
  [ 509.   391.    44.8]
  [ 685.   645.   166.4]
  [ 445.   549.   104.2]
  [ 655.   319.    93. ]
  [ 595.   329.    86. ]
  [ 497.   361.    60.4]
  [ 479.   387.    56.4]
  [ 695.   677.   197. ]
  [ 465.   159.   152.2]
  [ 729.   311.   149.6]
  [ 381.   453.   127.2]
  [ 685.   335.    96. ]
  [ 683.   709.   267.2]
  [ 409.   205.   139.4]
  [ 685.   295.   133.4]
  [ 313.   447.   123.8]
  [ 675.   557.   102. ]
  [ 461.   255.   100.6]
  [ 645.   323.    92. ]
  [ 465.   549.    86.2]]]
```

and here's the code:

```
import pyautogui
import cv2


def process(img):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (5, 5), 2)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 0)
    img_hough = cv2.HoughCircles(img_canny, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, minDist=10)
    print(img_hough)
    return img_canny


# region
firstThirdOfTheScreensWidth = int(pyautogui.size()[0] / 1.7)
heightOfTheScreen = pyautogui.size()[1]
starting_point_x = 100
starting_point_y = 200
region = (starting_point_x, starting_point_y,
          (firstThirdOfTheScreensWidth - starting_point_x), (heightOfTheScreen - (starting_point_y + 100)))

pyautogui.screenshot(region=region, imageFilename="whatTheBotSees.png")
processed_image = process(cv2.imread("whatTheBotSees.png"))
```

Comment: I think you need to find the right kind of preprocessing with gaussian blur, etc. so that HoughCircles can find the correct circles with the minRadius and maxRadius options. You may want to reupload the whatTheBotSees image as a png instead of jpeg, since the jpeg compression messes with reproduce-ability

Comment: if you want to get only circles in some region then maybe you could crop image to this region.

Comment: @furas the circles are pretty much dynamic, after pressing on one, it unlocks the ones joined to it, so I cannot really do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the correct circles by setting the min and max radius in HoughCircles to 35 and 53.

```
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
from cv2 import cv2

def process(img, minr=35, maxr=53):
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (5, 5), 2)
    img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 0)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img_canny, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, minDist=10, minRadius=minr, maxRadius=maxr)
    if len(circles) > 0:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
        return img_canny, circles
    else:
        return img_canny, None


raw_image = cv2.imread("whatTheBotSees.jpg")
processed_image, circles = process(raw_image)

#draw circles:
if circles is not None:
    for i in circles[0, :]:
        print("(center), radius:  (",i[0],  i[1],")", i[2])
        cv2.circle(raw_image, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.circle(raw_image, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow("Processed Image", raw_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

output list of circles:

```
(center), radius:  ( 579 259 ) 38
(center), radius:  ( 471 445 ) 38
(center), radius:  ( 681 443 ) 38
(center), radius:  ( 473 321 ) 37
(center), radius:  ( 579 505 ) 40
```

This is not a robust solution due to the the hand tuned radius parameters, but it might be good enough if all the images you are processing in this way are mostly identical to the test image you provided. If you need to identify those circles at other sizes or on other screens, you may need to add some more logic to identify the correct circles.

[image]